# Array in Controller laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Can anyone help me to fix my code ? i've the concept but dont know how to write them into code in controller

```
$temp=DB::table('temporary')->get();

    //dd($temp);
    if($temp['tahun'] < 'current year'){
        $temp['tahun'] = 'current year';
        $temp['nomor'] = 'nomor+1';
        $keluhan->no_laporan = $temp['nomor'];
    } else {
        $temp['nomor']++;
    }
```

Condition :
my table temporary has 2 attribute tahun(value=2017 int) and nomor (value=1 int)
i want to check if my tahun < this current year (real time year, idk the code so i write current year) then my tahun become = this curent year AND my nomor++ (+1 from its value first) how do i wrte them into laravel code ? please kindly help, thank you buddy

Comment: what is the variable `$keluhan` in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DB::table('temporary')->->get()** will return a collection. and from your code, it seems you are working with single column, you can use first().

For date can use simple date() function.

```
$temp=DB::table('temporary')->first();

//dd($temp);
if($temp->tahun < date("Y")){
    $temp->tahun = date("Y");
    $temp->nomor++;
    $keluhan->no_laporan = $temp->nomor;
} else {
    $temp->nomor++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$temp=DB::table('temporary')->get();` will get a collection. so you have to  loop. and Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to get the date.

```
foreach($temp as $temp)
{
  if($temp->tahun < Carbon\Carbon::now()->year){
    {
      $temp->tahun=Carbon\Carbon::now()->year;
      $temp->nomor=$temp->nomor+1;
      $temp->update();
     }
   else
    {
       $temp->nomor=$temp->nomor+1;
       $temp->update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Loading `Carbon` just to get the current year seems excessive when you can just use `date('Y')`.

Comment: @fubar Carbon is a built in feature of laravel and is much easier and semantic. with `date()` we have to deal with `strtotime`, formatting issues, lots of calculations, and more. and

Comment: Carbon is a dependency in Laravel, it's not built in. And to use `date('Y')` to get the current year you *do not* need to use `strtotime`, nor make any calculations whatsoever.

Comment: Ok. thank you for the information. I'll learn and make sure of it.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping its now work, great. God Bless You.